# Firefox extension, URL redirect from panel widget

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a Firefox addon. I created a beautiful panel widget with HTML and CSS. Now, I just need to get my scripts working from the panel widget. I try to redirect the current tab to the new url that is specified in the button value like below:

```
<button class="myBtnClass AllBtnStyles" value="www.example.com/info">Info</button>
```

I got this script in my file also;

```
$(".myBtnClass").click(function () {
        window.content.location.href = $(this).attr('value');      
    });
```

But on button click the current tab gets redirected to

```
resource://jid0-ulah35kcypxsda4kbau4uierkjw-at-jetpack/add-on-name/data/www.example.com/info
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change tab in panel's content script, you need to pass the address to add-on script.

So, in your panel's script:

```
$(".myBtnClass").click(function () {
    self.port.emit("changeTab", $(this).attr("value"));
});
```

In your add-on script, you need to listen to the port event: (assume your panel is named `panel`)

```
panel.port.on("changeTab", function(url) {
    var tabs = require("tabs");
    tabs.open(url); // open the url in a new tab
});
```

See documentation on `port` at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html